# JQuery toggle function not working in some mobile device browser like moto e

Tags: jquery, html

Below code is working fine in windows browsers but not working in some of the mobile device like moto-e. what should i do?

**Jquery**

```
$(".child-row .child-head").on("click", function () {
       $(this).next(".child-body").slideToggle();
       $(this).closest(".child-row").siblings().find('.child-body').slideUp();
});
```

**Html**

```
<div class="child-row">
     <div class="child-head">
           Head Text
     </div>
     <div class="child-body">
           Body Text
     </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Click events don't work as expected on touch enabled devices.](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/click_event_del.html) So only certain elements has clicks events defined, but you can define it manually. For example

```
$(".child-row .child-head").each(function(){
    this.onclick = function() {}
});
```

Also you can use a touch event

```
$(".child-row .child-head").on('touchstart', function() {...
```

Comment: Could you please add a JSFiddle?